# Layout of flexdashboard - having multiple tabsets

Tags: r, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I currently have my dashboard which looks like:

[image]

What I am trying to do is under the `Data` tab have additional tabs. For example I want to combine the `Table Population` tab with the `Graphic iris` tab so that the table and graphic are on the same page. Then in a new tab have the `Another tab-pag` (as it currently is).

How can I merge the two tabs to have them on the same page?

I would like this joined tab to look like the `Analysis` tab:

[image]

Dashboard:

````
---
title: "Analysis"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    #css: "custom_style.css"
    theme:
      base_font:
        google: Prompt
      code_font:
        google: JetBrains Mono
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinyjs)
library(gt)
library(gtExtras)
library(plotly)
```

MySidebar {.sidebar}
==============================

```{r}
useShinyjs(rmd = TRUE)

shinyWidgets::pickerInput(
  inputId = "select_species",
  label = h4("Species"),
  choices = unique(iris$Species),
  selected = unique(iris$Species[1]),
  multiple = TRUE,
  options = list(
    `actions-box`= TRUE,
    size = 10,
    `selected-text-format` = "count > 1"
  )
)

```


Introduction {data-vertical_layout=scroll}
==============================

Column {data-width=650 .main .tabset}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

Here is some introduction text

Data {data-vertical_layout=scroll}
==============================

IRIS Species {.tabset .tabset-fade}
-------------------------------------

### Table Population

```{r}

output$irisTable = render_gt({
  iris %>% 
    gt() %>% 
    gt_add_divider(columns = "Provincias", weight = px(3), color = "lightgrey", include_labels = FALSE)
})

div(style='height:800px; overflow-y: scroll',
    gt_output("populationTable")
)
```

### Graphic iris

```{r}
renderPlotly({
  ggplotly(
    iris %>%
      ggplot(aes(x = Species, y = Petal.Length)) +
      geom_bar() +
      theme_bw()
  )
})
```

### Another tab-page

Analysis {data-vertical_layout=scroll}
==============================

Column
-------------------------------------

### Tab 1

some text

### Tab 2

some more text
````

Comment: Do you not just need to replace the line `IRIS Species {.tabset .tabset-fade}` with `Column`?

Comment: Not exactly, doing this removes the tab panel - I want to put in a secondary tab-panel, say called, "IRIS" which contains 2 tabs:`Table Population` and `Graphic iris`, then next to the `IRIS` tab it will have `Another tab-page`

Comment: You may consider using [`shinydashboard::box`](https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/structure.html#boxes)